# Python MySQL wont connect to localhost

Tags: python, mysql, database, localhost, connector

So im currently making a database with MySQL and it wont work for some reason.

This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='name', passwd='12345')
```

I searched around a bit and found out i should try to change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' but i just got the same error.
This is the error i get:

```
PS C:\Users\name> & C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/name/Desktop/database/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Det gick inte att göra en anslutning eftersom måldatorn aktivt nekade det

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/name/Desktop/database/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='name', passwd='12345')
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 Det gick inte att göra en anslutning eftersom måldatorn aktivt nekade det)
PS C:\Users\name>
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You are sure that your mysql service is running?

Comment: How to i check if it is running?

Comment: How do i do that i cant figure out how it works.

Comment: You can't figure out if the service is running? Have you read one of the articles?

Comment: Yes i did but im new so i cant figure it out.